# How to pass checkbox's status to an angularjs function?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in orders|orderBy:'order_id'| filter:{ paid: '0' } ">                         
        <div class="col left">
          <button ng-click="viewOrderDetails(x.detail)">订单详情</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col left">
          <button ng-click="viewOrderDetails(x.detail)">打印订单</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col left">
          <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="subcheck" id="processed" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-model="x.processed" ng-click="changeProcessedStatus(processed)">上菜/未上菜<P>
        </div>
```

when I click checkbox (id="processed"), I want to pass checkbox's status to function changeProcessedStatus. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `x` as alias for your order, you should use directive using this alias. Change

```
ng-click="changeProcessedStatus(processed)">
```

to

```
ng-click="changeProcessedStatus(x.processed)"
```

Comment: x.processed will be in your controller scope, so is not needed to pass it inside the function